# Delete an object in a complicated array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

So the problem is easy to explain... I get and id I need to remove it from the array(allIds) and the object(byIds).

```js
const DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    todos: {
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      byIds: {
        "1": {
          content: "test1",
          completed: false,
        },
        "2": {
          content: "test2",
          completed: false,
        },
        "3": {
          content: "test3\\",
          completed: false,
        },
        "4": {
          content: "test4",
          completed: false,
        },
      },
    },
    visibilityFilter: "all",
  },
];
```

for the array(allIds I found how to do it

```js
  DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.allIds = DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.allIds.filter(
    (allId) => allId !== id
  );
```

but I don't know how can I remove it from the object.. thanks for the help I believe that's not too complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds['' + id]`

Answer (score 1):

```
var idToBeDeleted = 3;
delete DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds[idToBeDeleted ]
```